# PostgreSQL Repeatable Read Isolation Level "transaction start time"

Tags: postgresql, isolation-level, transaction-isolation, repeatable-read

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/transaction-iso.html#XACT-REPEATABLE-READ

The PostgreSQL documentation for the Repeatable Read Isolation Level states the following:

> `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `MERGE`, `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, and `SELECT FOR SHARE` commands behave the same as `SELECT` in terms of searching for target rows: they will only find target rows that were committed as of the transaction start time.

What is defined as the "transaction start time?" When I first read the statement, I interpreted it as the start of the transaction:

```
BEGIN;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
```

But in my testing, I find that according to that statement, the transaction start time is actually "the start of the first non-transaction-control statement in the transaction" (as mentioned earlier in the section). Is my conclusion correct, or am I misunderstanding the documentation?